# Parsing JSON in Android :(

Tags: android, json

I am learning Android, parsing JSON. This is my code:

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQMvY.png)

[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikUGC.png)

And this is result: [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqZ3B.png)

I don't understand why stringBuilder is null, it must be JSON. Please help :( .

Comment: Welcome! Please be sure to post properly formatted code and text, not images of code and text. This [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) lists many reasons why this is important.

Answer (score 1):

textView.setText(download.jsonString +"noway") look here. download.jsonString is always null because First you set it, then you process jsonString. You need to do the opposite.

textView.setText(download.jsonString +"noway") It is necessary to use this code inside the download class.

Comment: The textview just use to know logcat work or not, because in overide method i have Log.v("TAG", jsonString) and i don't see it in Logcat window. Secondly, i don't know how to put textview in inline class. Thank your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fixed this bug. Just add Internet permission :(

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).